# discord.js message reply to button

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I want to make the bot do a private message reply when the button is pressed. I know this is possible because I've seen it before, but how exactly do I do it? I tried to make it say that they successfully voted on the poll but it didn't work, instead I got an error, here is some more info:
**Code**

```js
client.ws.on('INTERACTION_CREATE', interaction => {
    if(interaction.data.component_type === 2) {
        client.api.interactions(interaction.id, interaction.token).callback.post({
            data: {
                type: 4,
                data: {
                    content: 'You have voted on this poll.',
                    flags: 64,
                }
            }
        })
    }
})
```

**Error**

```js
DiscordAPIError: Unknown interaction
    at RequestHandler.execute (C:\Users\--\Discord Bot --\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:154:13)
    at async RequestHandler.push (C:\Users\--\Discord Bot --\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:39:14) {
  method: 'post',
  path: '/interactions/854035073934295060/aW50ZXJhY3Rpb246ODU0MDM1MDczOTM0Mjk1MDYwOnpCa0Q0aDhpa1ZlWFR6QWZJRWRITG5sT21aa3RRYzlUSURZVjk4T2RBZHpMWE1YbHJ4NEtkZm01elRRZkdSOFNOWURHME95a0dKNjdWbnpKNllvN3hmMENKMnk2MHBJTm5CbDJvWnc3THdPVVJLYW1XNTB0N1RUbFhEQTdJWktP/callback',
  code: 10062,
  httpStatus: 404
}
```

I have done it before, but I may have done it a little differently. I don't remember what I did the last time though. I do think I did it like a slash command, like it is here. Here is what I want it to look like (I used slash command here to make it): [image: private message for user like Clyde's messages]

Comment: Sorry for using your time, it's because I did `button.defer()` so it couldn't find it.